# Managing heap with dynamically linked libraries

Tags: c++, c, dynamic-linking

I'm working on a project which should be able to load dynamically linked libraries at runtime through `dlopen`.

The core framework is finished and it is indeed working but I have some doubt about how to correctly manage objects allocated on the heap by the libraries. The interface to the library has just one method which returns a pointer to an object statically allocated inside the library which is a subtype of a common class with `virtual` methods

To explain it better I'll provide a stub of how I want it to work:

```
// header common to the core and to the libraries

class BaseSetting {
 ..
}

class DerivedSetting1 : public BaseSetting { .. }
class DerivedSetting2 : public BaseSetting { .. }

class ObjectInterface {
  private:
    vector<BaseSetting*> settings;

  protected:
    void registerSetting(Setting *setting) { settings.push_back(setting); }

  public:
    vector<Setting*> *getSettings() { return &settings; }
}

// library example

class ConcreteObject {
  ConcreteObject() {
    registerSetting(new ..);
    registerSetting(new ..);
  }

static ConcreteObject object;

extern "C" ConcreteObject *retrieve() { return &object; }
```

The main problem here is how I should manage the heap allocated settings of the library? I need polymorphism so I can't just store concrete objects inside the vector and at the same time I need to switch between libraries when needed, by unloading the current with `dlclose`, and release all the memory associated with them. I could use an `unique_ptr` but this would complicates things because I'll be able to use them from the core just by getting the raw pointer through `get()` which then would break any ownership.

Is there a common design pattern to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1):

The solution isn't really related to dynamic linking - the problem and its solution is the same whether your objects come from a shared library or is part of the main application as derived classes from a base-class. The only "extra" problem with dynamic libraries is that you obviously can't use `dlclose` while still having active objects created by code that resides in the dynamic library (unless you are 100% sure NOTHING will call any of the code in the DL, of course).

Your ObjectInterface needs to have a destructor that deletes the elements in `settings`,

Alternatively, you will need to have a `unregisterSetting` that is called somewhere suitable (e.g some destructor).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the attachment to [this](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/cpp-dependency-injection). `module.cc` and `client.cc` are external objects dynamically loaded into a shared context and collaborating with each other, `app.cc` is the associated magic to make it look `C++`. The way they are constructed/destructed is what you may find appropriate for your problem.

In essence, each pluggable type is supposed to inherit from a common interface `bootstrap_ifc` and have two methods with known interface available from the shared library.

```
extern "C" bootstrap_ifc* client_constructor()
{
  return new(std::nothrow) client;
}

extern "C" void client_destructor(bootstrap_ifc* obj)
{
  delete obj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a singleton which represents your library (you may use [singulatiry](https://github.com/boost-vault/Singularity) library for that). In constructor of this wrapper you will call dlopen and in destructor dlclose + delete all allocated objects.
Or you want something simpler - just implement functions init and destroy and call them in proper order:
dlopen -> init -> work with library -> destroy -> dlclose